# How to extract number only and sort in ascending from text file contains String and Int?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, loops

I'm a beginner in Java.
Please give me direction in solving the question.
Below code is what I have tried and extracted number only.
I'm lost after that.

```
public class regex {

    public static String str = "9, a, R, 3, 60, Z, 40, 30, 33, 29, DDD, aaa, !!, 21, 88, s, q, l, z, 2, a";

    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        str = str.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " ");

        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" ")));
    }
}
```

Console:

```
num:29
num:30
num:33
num:40
num:60
num:88
```

Comment: I would recommend using [isDigit()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/character_isdigit.htm), which will let you know if it is a digit. Just check if it is true.

Comment: `[^-?0-9]` says to not match anything in the set (literally). So you're matching any character except `-`, `?`, or the `0-9` range.

Comment: @ctwheels that seems fine to me.  By replacing non-numbers with spaces and splitting on spaces, she should end up with an array whose elements only have numbers.

Comment: Next step is to iterate through the array, convert the Strings to numbers, and sort them.  You could call `Integer.parseInt()` on each element, put the results into an `ArrayList<Integer>` and call `sort()` at the end.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem It does work, but it's a hiccup. I think the OP is trying to match the format of `-?\d+` (meaning a number that can possibly be negative)

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.  Like what if she had `?` in the input.  Fair enough.  For me, I wouldn't bother with the regular expression at all.  I'd just call Integer.parseInt() on everything in the list, and ignore the inevitable NumberFormatExceptions.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments and helps. I'll try all of them out!!!

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem you are right check my solution I only used `Integer.parseInt()` to check whether a string is numeric or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the regex needs a little fix:

> ```
> str = str.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " ");
> ```

The problem with it is that *it will not replace* `?` in the input.
Probably that's not what you intended.
Probably you want to keep `-` when it's followed by a digit,
and otherwise remove.
You can do that by doing two replacements:

```
str = str
    .replaceAll("[^-0-9]+", " ")
    .replaceAll("-(?![0-9])", " ");
```

Now, you can safely split the string on one or more spaces.
Then create a stream of `String` from the `String[]`,
then map it to `int` values,
then sort,
and finally create an array:

```
int[] ints = Arrays.stream(str.split(" +"))
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .sorted()
    .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
```

Another approach I find a bit easier to understand,
is to instead of splitting,
extract the numeric sequences using a `Pattern`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(-?\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    nums.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()));
}

Collections.sort(nums);
System.out.println(nums);
```

Comment: thank you thank you and thank you so much!!! I have been solving these for days and lost direction. You are the Java angle!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this approach:

1.Extract only numbers from the string to array list.

2.Sort the numbers in array list using **Collections**.

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
{  
    try  
    {  
      int num = Integer.parseInt(str);  
    }  
    catch(Exception e)  
    {  
      return false;  
    }  
    return true;  
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

     String str = "9, a, R, 3, 60, Z, 40, 30, 33, 29, DDD, aaa, !!, 21, 88, s, q, l, z, 2, a";
     ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     String[] strArr = str.split(",");
     for(int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++){
           if(isNumeric(strArr[i].trim())){
               numList.add(Integer.parseInt(strArr[i].trim()));
           }
     }
     Collections.sort(numList);
     System.out.println(numList);
}
```

**Output**:

```
[2, 3, 9, 21, 29, 30, 33, 40, 60, 88]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: thank you, Mr Oghli for giving such a wonderful answer. You taught me, a very beginner another approach to solve the question. Thank you for your time!!!

Answer (score -1):

Hope the below code answers your question: It just reads each line from the input file and extracts the strings using split method and store it in an array. Then it tries to convert the string to int. If the string is a numeric value,it will convert into int and add it to arraylist.If not, it will just skip. Then it sorts an arraylist using Collections.sort method and displays the result.

```
package TrialPrograms;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Stacktraceq2 {

    private static final Exception Exception = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("F:\\SeleniumTCs\\input.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fi));

        String strLine;
        ArrayList<Integer> nos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
              // Print the content on the console
              String[] arr = strLine.split(" ");

              for(int i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++) {
                  try {
                  int no=Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
                  nos.add(no);
                  }
                  catch(NumberFormatException e) {

                  }
              }
              Collections.sort(nos);

                }
        System.out.println("The Numbers in Ascending Order");
        for(int i:nos) {
            System.out.println(i);

    }

}

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!!
After executing your code, the console I got only 88.
The only things I changed was the text file path link.
The text file looks like below (each character has a new line):
9
a
R
3
60
Z
40
30
33
29
DDD
aaa
!!
21
88
s
q
l
z
2
a
------
May I know what is the problem?

Comment: I have solved the problem. Thank you so much!!!!
Wish you have a nice day.

Comment: May I know how if want to output the result in console to text file?

Comment: try {
             File file = new File("E:\\Eclipse Projects\\ST Electronics\\src\\withStackOverFlow_1\\answer.txt");
             
             if (!file.exists()) {
              file.createNewFile();
             }
             
             PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
             pw.println(i);
             pw.close();
             System.out.println("Done");
             
            }catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
But it doesn't work.

Comment: To write the output to a file you need to specify the output file path like this - FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("<OutputFilePath"); BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fo)); and you also need to replace the lines after the Collections.sort(nos) with the following code -  }
  for(int j=0;j<nos.size();j++) {
   bw.write(nos.get(j).toString() + " ");

 }
  br.close();
  bw.close();

}
 This code works for me. You can try..

Comment: I would give the credit to user janos because he is the first that replied to the post and give me very detail explanation and correction.
Your reply really means a lot to me. Hope you don't mind. Wish you have a great day. ;-)

Comment: I understand. That's ok. I don't mind. The credit should go to him as he replied you first with the correct answer. u too have a great day!!:)

Comment: Thank you, Dora. Nice to meet you here. ;-)